# auto detect addition and deletion of any file in any specificy directory and subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nfs, inotify

I am trying to write a tool to auto-detect any file addition or deletion to a specific directory. I know inotify can do this task in most efficent manner and code would be also shorter. But I cannot use inotify here as I am working on NFS directory , where inotify fail to detect any directory changes. (Which I understand) .

Here is a some rough code I wrote to monitor any directory , which is bad in many way. Also, sometimes it skip some events.

```
while true
    do

    touch temp_fs_state.log
    touch temp_1_fs_state.log

    find . -type f -ls |awk '{print $NF}' >> temp_fs_state.log
    sleep 1
    find . -type f -ls |awk '{print $NF}' >> temp_1_fs_state.log

    diffResult=$(diff  temp_fs_state.log temp_1_fs_state.log |grep -E '<|>' )

    echo $diffResult |grep -Fq '>'
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];then
       echo "`echo $diffResult | awk '{print $NF}'` ADDED to the target directory!!"
    fi
    echo $diffResult |grep -Fq '<'

    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];then
       echo "`echo $diffResult | awk '{print $NF}'` DELETED to the target directory!!"
    fi

    rm -rf temp_fs_state.log temp_1_fs_state.log

done
```

## Current result:

Some files are not detected by current solution.

```
sh monitor
./x9 DELETED to the target directory!!
./x11 ADDED to the target directory!!
./x13 ADDED to the target directory!!
./x14 ADDED to the target directory!!
./x15 ADDED to the target directory!!
./x17 ADDED to the target directory!!
./x17 DELETED to the target directory!!
```

## Question :

Can similar result would be achieved with any other shorter or smarter approach ?
Can we ensure no events are skipped ?

PS: Please assume , CPU performance is not concerned here as it's for testing purpose only.

Comment: You will miss anything that happens between creating `temp_1_fs_state.log` till you go through the loop again to create `temp_fs_state.log`.  Consider only doing one `find` per loop and comparing it to the previous run.

Comment: You can use `-newer` flag of `find` (with modifiers - look into the documentation). `touch` any file and look for files that are newer.

Comment: A nice approach is mentioned in this cross site [\[ answer \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249238/25919).

Comment: @sjsam --- for addition , it works . But for deletion its not working.

Comment: @soFan : Obviously, you have to tweak it a bit to work for addition ;)

Comment: thanks, I am on it . If I succeed I will post it here.

Comment: By the way, as your current code works, this question looks a bit off topic to me at the moment.. ;)